# ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID on publishing my web site on Windows AZURE

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created an ASP.NEt WEB API. I want to host this on Windows AZURE. I have successfully created the website on Windows Azure and downloaded the Publish Settings files for it.Now when I publish my Web API from VS-2012 on Windows 8 machine it asks me to import the publish settings file that i have recently downloaded. I provided it that file and when i click on the "Validate Connection" button it is failed. It is giving following errors.

[image]
[image]

I want to mention that I am behind a corporate firewall and using a proxy connection. If it is related to Firewall or Proxy then please tell me that what can I change to my Firewall / Proxy settings to make it working.

Thanks in Advance...